# r: Two plots in one window when using NbClust()

Tags: r, plot

Since I have loaded the "NbClust" package to my r session `library("NbClust")` the plot window (in the lower right corner of RStudio) is plotting **two** plots for each window (which in turn makes some of the plots very small)... 
Do you have any idea how I can switch this off and bring it back to plotting one plot per window?

Comment: Does `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` solve your issue?

Comment: I don't see any plot methods in the `NbClust` package, but there are a couple of places in the `NbClust` code that set `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` (two plots arranged in two columns). Resetting to a single plot (as in the code in my previous comment), should take care of it. For more on `mfrow` and other graphical parameters (for base graphics) see `?par`.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks, where in my code do I have to insert `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` exactly?
I tried to put it right after `library("NbClust")` but it did not change anything... sorry I am relatively new to r

Comment: Running it right after `library(NbClust)` should set it back to a single plot per window. That's what happened when I tested this on my machine.

Comment: In general, run `par(mfrow=c(x,y))` right before making one or more plots whenever you want to change the number of plots that display in a single window from the current setting to a new setting. To check the current setting, run `par("mfrow")`.

Comment: thats great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @eipi10 I finally found the solution for my problem:

I had to insert `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` after a series of `NbClust()` calls to have all subsequent plots in a single window each again. So, the code looks like

```
library("NbClust")

n1 = NbClust(...)
n2 = NbClust(...)
n3 = NbClust(...)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

When I placed the `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` right after the `library("NbClust")`then it did not work for whatever reason...

Comment: `NbClust` is probably resetting `mfrow` each time you run it. I'm going to file a bug report with the package maintainer, as the package functions should reset `mfrow` back to its previous value after running.

Comment: yeah, this sounds plausible